# Control errors with subcaption subfigure

Tags: captions, subfloats, subcaption

Code:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry,array,graphicx,float,caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}
        \includegraphics[width=5cm]{initial_uniform.eps}
        \caption{Uniform Distribution}
        \label{fig1a}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

I have the caption package installed and subcaption.sty is detected. However, when I use subfigure I am getting these errors:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \let 
l.72        \includegraphics
                       [width=5cm]{initial_uniform.eps}

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \let 
l.72        \includegraphics
                       [width=5cm]{initial_uniform.eps}
```

and more control errors.

When I comment out the lines for begin and end subfigure i.e use just normal figure, everything works just fine. I can't understand what is wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of `subfigure` is missing the `width`. Use

```
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
```

Second mandatory argument is the width of the sub figure.

Your code with this correction is

```
\documentclass[fleqn,11pt,a4paper,demo]{article}   %% remove demo
\usepackage{geometry,array,graphicx,float,caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        %\centering  %% may be you need this
        \includegraphics[width=5cm]{initial_uniform.eps}
        \caption{Uniform Distribution}
        \label{fig1a}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am sorry.. I did write `[width=5cm]` some mistake while pasting i guess. I tried both `width` and `scale`.

But setting subfigure width fixed the issue. I didn't know that was necessary. Thanks

Comment: @bharat_iyengar Oh! OK. I modified the answer.

Comment: One more thing. My captions are coming on the left side of the figure instead of bottom. How to fix it?

Comment: @bharat_iyengar Can you show the code that produces this undesired effect?

Comment: It is the same as I posted. Plus the subfigures are not aligned side by side. They are stacked. Perhaps because of the side captions.

Comment: @bharat_iyengar: Since I don't get that behaviour, I am clueless.

Comment: I forgot to mention. The source of that behaviuor is because of the way the eps is written by MATLAB. The co-ordinates are a little screwed up. Resaving the eps using inkscape corrects that problem. Mathworks doesn't seem to fix this issue. It has been there since malab 7.